# tikz node does not fit as expected when yscale used in geometry

Tags: tikz-pgf, geometry, tikz-node, fit

I am trying to make a rectangular node fit around two other nodes. This works fine as long as I do not set `xslant`and `yscale` in the enclosing `scope`. In the example below, the enclosing node does not fit `(n1)` and `(n2)`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{scopes,fit,backgrounds}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1,transform shape]

  \tikzstyle{tA}=[draw,fill=red!10!yellow]
  \tikzstyle{tB}=[draw,fill=red!30!yellow]
  \tikzstyle{geom}=[xslant=1.5,yscale=0.5,rotate=0]

  \begin{scope}[geom]
    \node[tA] (n1) at (0,0) {A};
    \node[tB] (n2) at (0,1) {A};
    \node[tA] (n3) at (1,0) {A};
    \node[tB] (n4) at (1,1) {A};

    \node[fit=(n1) (n2), draw] {x};   
    \draw[blue,->] (n1.south) -- (n1.north); \draw[blue,->] (n2.south) -- (n2.north);     
  \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is what I get (black line):

[image]

Comment: I really am not sure. The north and south look right. I added the output I get.

Comment: @marmot: even then the enclosing node is too small. And it depends whether the fitting is done in the original coordinate space or after transformation. If it is done in the original space then things should work smoothly.

Comment: Well, I actually want a rectangle in the original plane, i.e. a diamond in the final image. The diamond shape is therefore right, but it should not not intersect the smaller nodes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77954/discussion-between-user52366-and-marmot).

Comment: I have to deal with the same problem. An old picture has to be recompiled and does not.

Answer (score 2):

Interestingly, the very same code produces what I expect (see below) on a Xubuntu 10.10 system I installed to test this (pgf version is 2.00). So to me this seems to be a regression in Tikz/PGF... (pgf version 3.0.1a in my current Kubuntu installation)

[image]

Comment: Nice answer, +1. It might be interesting to know what has changed. Any chance you can provide a link to the old code?

Comment: I did a diff. There are mainly two larger blocks of code that changed... Too much to post here. V2.0 is here but the code is only there as an archive: https://sourceforge.net/projects/pgf/files/pgf/version%202.00/pgf-2.00.tar.gz/download